# cell.imageView.image and indentationLevel on iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview, ios7

How to make a distance between the image and the text closer?
In ios 6 the same code displays normally, but in the new version of the distance increased.

I do everything by standard methods

```
[cell.textLabel setText: .....

// cell.indentationLevel = 0; // this is for test

UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed: @ "image10.png"];
             NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (img);
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

attached image
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt119xgozvzzstd/image01.png

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the indentation level only affects the text. So when you're changing the indentation level/width you are in fact changing the distance between the `imageView` and the `textLabel`.

I tested this an unfortunately you can't make the `indentationWidth` negative. Thus you will need to subclass the `UITableViewCell` and set it up with your own views (I would suggest doing that in the Storyboard, with autolayout and make the `indentation` into a `NSLayoutConstraint` so that you have a property on your cell `indentationConstant`, for example which you can change). I have done this for a slightly different purposes, I needed to indent the whole `contentView`. No way around subclassing and creating custom views in Storyboard, sorry. (I am not even going to suggest some terrible hacks of accessing the subviews and modifying their frame, everything is autolayout today).